# Veracode - XSS Attack on HttpResponse BinaryWrite. How should it be fixed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, static-code-analysis, veracode

The following is the **c#** code in a aspx file that gets a pdf file and downloads it. To generate the pdf, the API server is given a html template content.

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{

    var apiUrl = <APIServer> + "/api/GetPdfByteData";
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(apiUrl);

    Template template = GetTemplate(); //Body property has got the HTML template
    string templateBody = template.Body;//html template 

    var values = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    values.Add("html", templateBody);

    var jsonStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(values);
    var stringContent = new StringContent(jsonStr, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    //uses an API service to get the pdf content for the template 
    var response = client.PostAsync(apiUrl, stringContent).Result; //VERACODE - Basic XSS STARTED here
    var pdfContent = response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        Response.Clear();
        Response.BinaryWrite(pdfContent);//VERACODE - this line has been highlighted for the XSS ENDED HERE 
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", pdfContent.Length.ToString());
        Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment;FileName=\"testfile.pdf\""));
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

The following is the medium severity warning.

> CWD ID:80 Exploitability: Neutral Category: Improper Neutralization of
>   Script-Related HTML Tags in a Web Page (Basic XSS)

The application also has got a *Content Security Policy* set for all the responses.

How should the API response with a byte array be handled safely for file download without any security vulnerability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added a piece of code to store the data in a secured temporary directory and do a scan on the files in the directory. This is to ensure there is no vulnerable or unwanted data, before streaming the file for download operation.

This mitigated the issue highlighted by Veracode Analysis and the fix already passed the Static Code Analysis.

Answer (score 2):

In theory, you should sanitize the output you get from `/api/GetPdfByteData`. In your code snippet, the response from that API is just used as response for your service, but could contain untrusted data. 
In your case, the response will not be rendered in the browser so you don't have the XSS risk, but you still have the risk of inserting unwanted data in your PDF. This unwanted data could for example exploit some vulnerabilities in PDF viewers (e.g. buffer overflow).
The main message is to make sure you check what you include in your PDF. If you pass user input in your PDF directly, you probably have a smell. If you fully control the API `/api/GetPdfByteData`, transferred the response securely and already checked the inputs that determine the response of the API, then you already mitigated the problem there and you can ignore this warning.

Comment: I agree with you. And Yes, `/api/GetPdfByteData` is another in-house, secured API that returns the **Bytedata**. What I originally wanted to understand is that 'is there a safe way to sanitize byte-data(similar to how `HtmlEncode` is used to sanitize user input data) to mitigate this warning?'. I think, I will need to work with _Veracode_ to safely ignore this warning. Thanks for response, @hermi